# Multiple Tables Vs one table for e-commerce product store combination

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-design

I am running an e-commerce site with multiple stores and each store having its products. I currently have a table called product-store which has a list of all product id referencing the products name and description from a different table , prices etc and their corresponding store ids. This table could have same product repeating multiple times if multiple store carry it.

I am mooting the idea of having a separate table for each store(product-store1, product-store2) rather than having all stores in one product-store table. I could be adding 100 stores and hence 100 tables like this. The structure of each table is the same but the reason why I am thinking of doing this is for better encapsulation of data from the other stores. However this would also mean identifying the corresponding table first for the store and then fetching the data.

I need help in assessing if this is a right approach and how I can measure the two approaches.

Comment: I've amended the tags - PHP didn't seem to be relevant to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are very few good reasons for splitting a table into multiple tables.  Here are reasons *not* to do it:

- SQL is optimized for large tables, but not for lots of small tables with the same structure.  (With small tables, you end up with lots of partially filled data pages.)
- Maintenance is a nightmare.  Adding a column, changing a data type, and so on has to be repeated many times.
- A simple query such as "How many stores sell a single product?" are problematic.
- You cannot have a foreign key relationship into this table, for instance, to have a history of prices or discounts on the product in each store.

A single table is almost always the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it also depends on if the products might be shared across different stores. I would not go the way of creating x tables for x stores, but a general structure to be able to hold all the information.

If so, you could set up at least three tables:

- product (holds all the generic products information, shop independent)
- store (information about the stores)
- store_product (links the products to the stores)

This way you can add as many products / stores to your system without having to change database structure (which is bad anyways).

To answer some of your assumptions:

- Encapsulation of data from different stores is rather selecting a subset of data that choosing different tables.
- whenever you need some additional information (not being thought of in the beginning) for either stores or products, its easier to add by referencing the new table to stores/products instead of having to multiply those changes by the amount of stores.